# Spring WebFlux Test Throwing "IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext" Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-webflux

I created a simple Spring WebFlux REST api and I wanted to write test cases to test it end to end (No mocking).

But it is throwing error message.

Here are my classes.

**Rest Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "list")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity> getusersList() {
        return userService.getusers();
    }
```

**Rest Controller Test Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
public class UserControllerTestIT {
   @Mock
   private UserService userService;

   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient webTestClient;

   @Test
    public void testApplicationsList() {
        this.webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/users/list")
                .exchange();
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error message. How to fix the issue ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Comment: Could you try using `@MockBean private UserService userService;` instead of `@Mock private UserService userService;`?

Answer (score 4):

If you are running a test with `SpringRunner.class` then you need to use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`.

Please refer to the spring boot  [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
public class UserControllerTestIT {
   @MockBean
   private UserService userService;

   @Autowired
   private WebTestClient webTestClient;

   @Test
    public void testApplicationsList() {
        this.webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/users/list")
                .exchange();
    }
}
```

Also,`@WebFluxTest` is used in combination with `@MockBean` or `@Import` to create any collaborators required by your `@Controller` beans.